# Tomcat6 http error 404

Tags: html, localhost, web

I want to start a server using apache tomcat. I have run the tomcat6.exe and the DOS windows popped out and said server was started. Then I created a simple html code and want to start it using localhost8080 in the browser, but resulted in http error. I placed my html file and renamed it index.jsp on the desktop. Is there any configuration I have to configure before starting the server? thx

Comment: Is this a typo or did you miss the colon? localhost:8080

Answer (score 1):

You must take a look over here... this might be helpful..

http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-3.2-doc/tomcat-apache-howto.html#configuring_tomcat